# Can I use attr: in description field of metadata in setup.cfg?

Tags: setuptools, setup.py, pypi, python-packaging

I try to use `attr:` in description but PyPi dispays `attr: round_utils.__doc__` instead of value of that expression.

Docs says I cannot use `attr:` in description. Look at the Metadata table (link below):
https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide/declarative_config.html#metadata

But I had done like here: https://github.com/zifter/numeral-system-py, because I saw the package description works in PyPi https://pypi.org/project/numeral-system-py/.

Attaching my files and links:

**`setup.cfg`**

```
[metadata]
name = round-utils
version = 1.0.4
author = Marchenko Ilya
author_email = mrmar333@yandex.ru
home-page = https://github.com/IliyaZinoviev/round-utils.git
description = attr: round_utils.__doc__
license = MIT
license-file = LICENSE
platform = any
keywords = round, utils, number
classifiers =
    Intended Audience :: Developers
    License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License
    Programming Language :: Python
    Programming Language :: Python :: 3.8
    Operating System :: OS Independent

[options]
zip_safe = false
include_package_data = true
python_requires = >= 3.8
package_dir =
    round_utils=source/round_utils
    tests=source/tests
packages =
    round_utils
test_suite = tests
setup_requires =
    setuptools >=30.3.0     # minimal version for `setup.cfg`

[bdist_wheel]
universal = true

[check]
metadata = true
strict = true

[sdist]
formats = gztar
```

**`round_utils.__init__py`**

```
"""Package for rounding functions"""

from .round import round_up, round_down

__all__ = [
    'round_up',
    'round_down'
]
```

PyPi link: https://test.pypi.org/project/round-utils/

Github repo: https://github.com/IliyaZinoviev/round-utils

Comment: I don't think you can have `setup_requires = setuptools >=30.3.0 `. This probably won't have the expected effect (I am not sure). Nowadays it is better to use a `pyproject.toml` to do this.

Comment: @sinoroc, thank you for answer. I will try it

Comment: Looking at _setuptools_ current code, it doesn't look like `attr:` is supported for `description`. I am not sure that it actually does work in that other project you mentioned as a reference, since they have not had any release since they [changed](https://github.com/zifter/numeral-system-py/commit/fb065bb87907af9c3b8ac3ea2289f84e83935e98) that `description` configuration to use `attr:`.

Comment: @sinoroc,Your absolutely right! Thank you again!
I checked last package release and it has the same problem.
https://test.pypi.org/project/numeral-system-py/0.2.1a0/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't use `attr:` for the `description` configuration value of *setuptools*' `setup.cfg`. As of *setuptools 51.1.0* (today's newest version), it is not supported. The project you linked to as a reference has not seen a release since they [changed](https://github.com/zifter/numeral-system-py/commit/fb065bb87907af9c3b8ac3ea2289f84e83935e98) to (incorrectly) using `attr:` for their `description`, and as can be seen [here](https://test.pypi.org/project/numeral-system-py/0.2.1a0/) it does not seem to work (as expected).